# Have issue with ExtJS submit form, unable to decode JSON response

Tags: json, forms, extjs, submit, root

I am using an ExtJS form submit to submit form data to web server. Based on the result of the submission, I need to alert the user. I was previously sending a response of the format

'{"success": "false", "msg": "Error creating Item. Please try again."}'

and this worked fine using the success property for the form.submit. However, I've had to adjust the format of the response to

'{"data":[{"success": "false", "msg": "Error creating Item. Please try again."}]}'

as this is the JSON format required by a separate module also accessing the same result.

Is there anyway to have the form.submit read the information correctly despite it now being wrapped in the root element?

Comment: Why did you have to adjust the format of the response?

Comment: There is also a Titanium Appcelerator app that is requesting the same information and the parseJSON function there requires the format with the root.

Comment: Ok, then you'll probably have to override one the methods in the form submit class. An easier way, however, would be to simply adjust your server side code to provide multiple return formats, depending on the requesting app.

Comment: Considered, but wanted to see first if there was another way, since there are several different functions that will be returning responses and it would require creating separate returns for each. Thanks though, Vlad's suggestions appears to have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form have "[reader](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-cfg-reader)" property. Try configure it:

```
reader: {
    root: 'data'
}
```